# Error with a JSON parser and a listview

Tags: android, json, listview, logcat

I made an app for my website which takes som information from my website brainstorm.web44.net
(those posts are just for testing!) and puts them  in a custom listview.

Here is the java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    JSONArray titles;
    HttpClient client;
    final static String URL = "http://brainstorm.net.com/?json=1";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String[] from = new String[] { "Title", "Description" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txtTitle, R.id.txtContent };

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> fillMaps;
        try {

            fillMaps = setContentAndTitle(new Read().execute("title").get(),
                    new Read().execute("content").get());
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps,
                    R.layout.list_item, from, to);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

    private List<HashMap<String, Object>> setContentAndTitle(String[] titles,
            String[] descriptions) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        for (int number = 0; number < titles.length; number++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("Title", titles[number]);
            map.put("Description", descriptions[number]);
            fillMaps.add(map);
        }
        return fillMaps;
    }

    public JSONArray Title() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException,
            JSONException {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
        HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
        int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status == 200) {
            HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            JSONArray brainstorm = new JSONArray(data);
            return brainstorm;
        } else {

            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> {

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<String> titlesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                titles = Title();
                for (int i = 0; i < titles.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject title = titles.getJSONObject(i);
                    String s = title.getString("title");
                    titlesArray.add(s);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String[] arr = toStringArray(titlesArray.toArray());
            return arr;
        }

        private String[] toStringArray(Object[] array) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] arr = new String[array.length];
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            arr[i]=array[i].toString(); 
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Logcat :

```
06-27 18:11:32.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1809): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 18:11:32.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1809):     at com.tendariusprod.brainstorm.MainActivity.setContentAndTitle(MainActivity.java:64)
06-27 18:11:32.768: E/AndroidRuntime(1809):     at com.tendariusprod.brainstorm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
```

Json :

```
{
"status": "ok",
"count": 2,
"count_total": 2,
"pages": 1,
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 17,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "json-parser",
        "url": "http://brainstorm.web44.net/?p=17",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "JSON Parser",
        "title_plain": "JSON Parser",
        "content": "<p>JSON Parser!</p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>JSON Parser!</p>\n",
        "date": "2013-06-27 09:02:55",
        "modified": "2013-06-27 09:02:55",
        "categories": [],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "admin",
            "name": "admin",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "admin",
            "url": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "custom_fields": {
            "single_layout": [
                "0"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "supermoon-ready-to-be-seen",
        "url": "http://brainstorm.web44.net/?p=14",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Supermoon ready to be seen!",
        "title_plain": "Supermoon ready to be seen!",
        "content": "<p>You will see the moon in its all splendore tonight!</p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>You will see the moon in its all splendore tonight!</p>\n",
        "date": "2013-06-26 16:56:19",
        "modified": "2013-06-26 17:18:11",
        "categories": [],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "admin",
            "name": "admin",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "admin",
            "url": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "custom_fields": {
            "single_layout": [
                "0"
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

Edit: this is a new code for the asynctask:

```
  public class Read extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
                HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
                int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
                    JSONObject o =new JSONObject(data);
                    titles = new JSONArray(o.getString("posts"));
                } else {
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    t.show();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < titles.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject title = titles.getJSONObject(i);
                    String s = title.getString("title");
                    String b = title.getString("content");
                    descArray.add(b);
                    titlesArray.add(s);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

            String[] arr1 = toStringArray(titlesArray.toArray()), arr2 = toStringArray(descArray
                    .toArray());

            for (int number = 0; number < arr1.length; number++) {
                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("Title", arr1[number]);
                map.put("Description", arr2[number]);
                fillMaps.add(map);

                String[] from = new String[] { "Title", "Description" };
                int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txtTitle, R.id.txtContent };


                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, fillMaps, R.layout.list_item, from, to);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            }

        }
```

Comment: `fillMaps = setContentAndTitle(new Read().execute("title").get(),
                    new Read().execute("content").get())`. this is null `fillMaps`.

Comment: ok.. thank you.. but how can i fix this.. i can't figure out..

Comment: why can't you get your data with a single asynctask? post your asynctask code.

Comment: are you sure its a json. try opening the url in a browser and check. i tried logging in the response its hmtl

Comment: i use wordpress and a json plugin

Comment: i don't know about that but i tried to get the response from the url and its not json.

Comment: it was .net not .com... but i still get the same error!

Comment: ok now i will try fixing the same

Comment: i parsed the json to get title and content. will post the code in few minutes.

Comment: Daniel Daius did you try the below? does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse with a single asynctask and display data in listview. I have used custom listview to display the content and title.

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    JSONArray titles;
    HttpClient client;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    final static String URL = "http://brainstorm.web44.net/?json=1";
    ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         new Read().execute();

    }


    public class Read extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pd.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();
           CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter();
           setListAdapter(cus);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                 String line = null;
                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                         sb.append(line + "\n");
                 }
                 is.close();
                 String result=sb.toString();
                 try {
                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsono.getString("posts"));
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++)
                    {
                    JSONObject job1 = (JSONObject) jsonarray.get(i);    
                    String titl = job1.getString("title");
                    String con = job1.getString("content");
                    title.add(titl);
                    content.add(con) ;
                    Log.i("......", titl);
                    Log.i("......", con);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
 class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
     LayoutInflater mInflater;
     public CustomAdapter()
     {
     mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);  
     }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return title.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder; 

        if (convertView == null) { 
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, 
                    parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(); 
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 

           convertView.setTag(holder); 
       } else { 
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
       } 

       holder.tv1.setText(title.get(position)); 
       holder.tv2.setText(content.get(position)); 

       return convertView; 
    }

 }
 static class ViewHolder
 { 
     TextView tv1,tv2;

 }
}
```

list_itemt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: i used a simple adapter... is this better?

Comment: its your choice. custom adapter gives you more options for customizing the layout inflated.

Comment: `fillMaps = setContentAndTitle(new Read().execute("title").get(),
                    new Read().execute("content").get())` this is statement is the cause.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. check the topic under threading rules. `The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)`.

Comment: its upto you to use simple adapter or custom adapter but you are trying to run asynctask symultaneously which is not possible

Comment: so except for that line an custom adapter you can use the asynctask in my code. the rest is upto you to modify. but if you wish to use custom adapter you can use the above.

Comment: remove that method itself. you are not doing it right. use 1 asynctask and get the sjon form url. parse the data and then collect it in list. then display the same.

Comment: i removed it.. the code is posted.. the same error at the for loop

Comment: there are so many mistakes. you cannot update ui from doinbackground. do in background runs in the background thread. you should not update ui from doinbackground. `Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); t.show();` not possible in doinbackground. you are running into new errors. i suggest you use the above.